# Overriding QObject::setProperty

Tags: c++, qt, properties

I would like override the `QObject::setProperty(const char*, QVariant)` because when I call this method with a `QVariant` which contains a `QVariantList` the method fail because it doesn't convert the `QVariantList` to `QList<UnknownType>`.

Any suggestions?

***EDIT***

I have the abstract class `Node` which contains

> ```
> Context* _context;
> QMap<QString, QString> _inputsPersisted;
> QMap<QString, QString> _outputsPersisted;
> ```

The `Node` class has also a `virtual void runImplementation()` and the method `void run()` like this :

> ```
> void Node::run()
> {
>     //get inputs from Context
>     for(QMap<QString, QString>::iterator it = _inputsPersisted.begin() ; it != _inputsPersisted.end() ; ++it )
>     {        
>         QVariant attribute = property(it.key().toStdString().c_str());
>         if(!attribute.isValid())
>         {
>             qWarning() << QObject::tr("%1:%2: Node::run:%3: the property %4 does not exist.").arg(__FILE__).arg(__LINE__).arg(_id.toString()).arg(it.key());
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             QVariant v = _context->getDataPersisted(it.value());
>             if(!v.isValid())
>                 qWarning() << QObject::tr("%1:%2: Node::run:%3: %4 is not in the context.").arg(__FILE__).arg(__LINE__).arg(_id.toString()).arg(it.value());
>             else
>                 if(v.type() != attribute.type())
>                     qWarning() << QObject::tr("%1:%2: Node::run:%3: %4 and %5 have not the same type.").arg(__FILE__).arg(__LINE__).arg(_id.toString()).arg(it.key()).arg(it.value());
>                 else
>                     if(!setProperty(it.key().toStdString().c_str(), v))
>                         qWarning() << QObject::tr("%1:%2: Node::run:%3: the property %4 have not been setted.").arg(__FILE__).arg(__LINE__).arg(_id.toString()).arg(it.key());
>         }
>     }
>     runImplementation();
>     //set outputs in the Context        
>     for(QMap<QString, QString>::iterator it = _outputsPersisted.begin() ; it != _outputsPersisted.end() ; ++it )
>     {
>         QVariant attribute = property(it.key().toStdString().c_str());
>         if(!attribute.isValid())
>         {
>             qWarning() << QObject::tr("%1:%2: Node::run:%3: the property %4 does not exist.").arg(__FILE__).arg(__LINE__).arg(_id.toString()).arg(it.key());
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             _context->setDataPersisted(it.value(), attribute);
>         }
>    }
> ```
>
> }

The `Context` class is like this :

> ```
> class Context : public QObject
> {
> Q_OBJECT
> public:
> Context(Context* parent = NULL) : : _parent(parent){}
> void setDataPersisted(QString name, QVariant value)
> {
>     if(_parent != NULL && _parent->exist(name))
>         _parent->setDataPersisted(name, value);
>     else
>     {
>         if(_stack.contains(name))
>             _stack.insert(name, value);
>         else
>             _stack.insert(name, value);
>      }
> }
> QVariant getDataPersisted(QString name)
> {
>     QVariant v;
>     QMap<QString, QVariant>::iterator it = _stack.find(name);
>     if(it != _stack.end())
>         v.setValue(it.value());
>     else
>         if(_parent != NULL)
>             v.setValue(_parent->getDataPersisted(name));
>     return v;
> }
> private:
> bool exist(QString name)
> {
>     bool contains = _stack.contains(name);
>     return contains || ((_parent != NULL) && (_parent->exist(name)));
> }
> private:
>     Context * _parent;
>     QMap<QString, QVariant> _stack;
> };
> ```

With this a `Node` child class can put and get some variables in her `Context`, and this, only by declare her properties and initialize the `_inputsPersisted` and `_outputsPersisted`. All the logic is done by the `Node` class.

Now I would like add a mechanism. I would like manipulate list in a `Context` and do a `append`.
For this, I modify the `Context::setDataPersisted` method:

> ```
> void setDataPersisted(QString name, QVariant value)
> {
>     if(_parent != NULL && _parent->exist(name))
>         _parent->setDataPersisted(name, value);
>     else
>     {
>         if(_stack.contains(name) && _stack.find(name)->value().canConvert(QVariant::List))
>         {
>             QVariantList toChange = qvariant_cast<QVariantList>(_stack.find(name)->value());
>             toChange.append(value);
>             _stack.insert(name, toChange );
>         }
>         else
>             _stack.insert(name, value);
>      }
> }
> ```

With this, after a `setDataPersited`, another `setDataPersisted` (to "append") and a `getDataPersisted` the data's list are corrupted.

Comment: overload the setter function?

Comment: What prevents you from doing that conversion yourself?

Comment: If you overload `QObject::setProperty`, then you will cook custom Qt library, and this library wont be compatible with another Qt libraries. Try doing conversion yourself as @vahancho sais and avoid modifying Qt library.

Comment: Btw, you cannot override `QObject::setProperty()` function because it is not a virtual one.

Comment: Ok. I use the `setProperty` method in a `Node` class  to initialize property of children class. The `Node` class will be in a sdk but the children class won't be in the sdk. So I have no idea of the property real type that I must initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro to register `QVariantList` withing Qt metatype system. This will allow storing `QVariantList` as `QVariant`

```
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVariantList);
...
    QVariantList var;
    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue<QVariantList>( var );
    QVariantList lst = v.value<QVariantList>();
```

To convert `QList<SomeType>` to `QVariantList`:

```
QList<SomeType> lst1;
...
QVariantList    lst2;

for (const SomeType& st : lst1)
    lst2.append( QVariant::fromValue<SomeType>( st ) );
```

To convert `QVariantList` to `QList<SomeType>` :

```
QVariantList    lst2;
...
QList<SomeType> lst1;

for (const QVariant& st : lst2)
    lst2.append( st.value<SomeType>() );
```

**Edit 1:**

```
auto it = _stack.find(name);
if (_stack.end() == it) {
    it = _stack.insert( name, QVariant::fromValue<QVariantList>(QVariantList()) );
}
QVariantList toChange = it->value().value<QVariantList>();
toChange.append(value);
_stack.insert(name, QVariant::fromValue<QVariantList>(toChange) );
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is I don't know `SomeType`. Maybe there is a solution using `QMetaType`?

Comment: @artoon If you have a list of qvariants, each of which is different type, you may use QVariant::canConvert and  QVariant::convert  functions

Comment: Yes but in my case they have all the same type. How I can use `QVariant::convert`?

Comment: @artoon use QVariant::value template function

Comment: But I can't use `QVariant::value` in my `Node` class because with this, `Node` class won't be independante of property real type.

Comment: @artoon now, it is completely unclear what you're doing. Show minimal code example.